# Convergence of Poisson integral at boundary of half plane.

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

My question is given $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and defining
$$
f_{\epsilon}(u)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)\frac{\epsilon}{(t-u)^2+\epsilon^2}dt,
$$
whether $f_\epsilon$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$? If not, then is it true if $f$ has compact support or for $L^p$ spaces with $p>1$?

Comment: $f_{\epsilon}\rightarrow f$ holds in $L^p$ if $f \in L^p$ f for some $1 \le p < \infty$. It can't hold for all $f\in L^p$ where $p=\infty$ because a general $f \in L^{\infty}$ cannot be approximated in $L^{\infty}$ by a continuous function, which $f_{\epsilon}$ is for $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I seem to recall seeing this covered in Duren's book on $H^p$ spaces.